# Java while loop query

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, methods, conditional-statements

This `while` code works fine, it is a program to check for palindromes.

```
public class Solution {
    public static boolean checkPalindrome(String str){
        int i=0;
        int j= str.length()-1;
        while(i<j)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(j))
            {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But what will happen in this version, what do you expect the output to be in this?

```
public class Solution {
    public static boolean checkPalindrome(String str){
        int i=0;
        int j= str.length()-1;
        while(i<j)
        {
          if(str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(j))
          {
              return false;
          }
          else
          {
              return true;
          }
          i++;
          j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you run it and see for yourself?

Comment: Is this an assignment for us ? Or you want to ask something else ?

Comment: The second code is wrong because it will only check the first and last character in the string. `return` exits the loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code block you are first checking if the first character is the same as the last.

If it isn't, return false.

Else, return true.

So this isn't going to be a valid palindrome check. It only checks if the first and last letters are the same or not and ignores the letters in the middle.